# PowerShell Script showing Exit Code 1 in Event Viewer

Tags: powershell

I'm very new to power shell and I've been asked to produce a script that checks a specific folder and determines if any .xml files have been sitting in this folder for longer than 2 hours. The script I wrote does work but when it is deployed to the biztalk server it generates this exit code of 1.  I'm uncertain if this script is causing the issue that we are now experiencing with that server or not so i'm hoping that someone here might be able to provide some insight.

```
    param(
        [String]$folderPath, 
        [int] $hoursToCheck
     )

$folderExists = Test-Path $folderPath

If((Get-Date).DayOfWeek.value__ -eq 0 -or (Get-Date).DayOfWeek.value__ -eq 6)
{
    exit
}

If($folderExists -eq $false)
{

    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "mail server" -To "email address" -From "email address" -Subject "email subject." -Body "email message"
}

ElseIf(Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath | Where-Object {$_.Extension -like "*.xml" -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-Date).AddHours($hoursToCheck)})
{

    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "email server" -To "address" -From "address" -Subject "email message" -Body "email body"
}
```

Comment: how is it deployed to the biztalk server?

Comment: we are using the windows task scheduler.  running under an account with local admin privileges.

Comment: so it has nothing to do with biztalk really?

Comment: i'm believe that there are separate issues occurring but I've been asked to go over the script and figure out why it is reporting an exit code of 1.  I've spent several hours researching what causes the exit code to set to 1

Answer (score 0):

Do you remember to input a negative value for the hours?

A good way to troubleshoot what is going on, is to use the write-verbose command. Here is a modified version of your script with the cmdletbinding() in the top, which allow you to use the verbose parameter when you run the script. I've changed the sign for the hours, so I subtract the hours. You run the script with the -verbose parameter e.g. .\.ps1 C:\xml_folder 2 -Verbose

```
        [cmdletbinding()]
      param(
            [String]$folderPath, 
            [int] $hoursToCheck
         )

    $folderExists = Test-Path $folderPath
    $currentDate=get-date

    If((Get-Date).DayOfWeek.value__ -eq 0 -or (Get-Date).DayOfWeek.value__ -eq 6)
    {
        write-verbose 'exit here'
        exit
    }

    If($folderExists -eq $false)
    {

        write-verbose 'folder does not exist'
    }

    ElseIf(Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -filter '*.xml' | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $currentDate.AddHours(-$hoursToCheck)})
    {

        write-verbose 'xml file exists' 
    }
    else
    {
        write-verbose "no old xml files in folder $folderpath"
    }
```

Comment: Also make sure to check the executionpolicy on the server. Are you allowed to run a PowerShell script?